# 1980s version of printf in C

Tags: c

In a well-known article by Ken Thompson, ( [http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf) )

in figure 1, that formats printf with decimal %d

```
printf("\t%d, \n", s[i]);
```

Why would that be done? Shouldn't it have been %c with character format? Why not? Was printf different during that time? Which version of C is the one in figure 1 in the article?

Comment: `char` is an integer type, and such printable with format specifiers for integers. Type promotion rules cause it to be converted to `int` when passed on a variadic argument list, which makes `%d` a valid format specifier for `char`. Strictly speaking, `%hhd` is preferred for `char`, but this might have not existed back then; this is probably the only part that might be retro-specific.

Comment: This sounds like a straight CS question (and rather clear when reading the program at whole (check the data definition) / paper ). Not sure what the retro part here should be.

Comment: @Raffzahn It doesn't say which version of C is used in the article. Usually C89 is the oldest standard I read about. Before that it was "K&R C"

Comment: @NiklasR. This seems much like a question about a programs intend - in this case printing the decimal value of each byte in an array (so it can be examined). It works with any C version (supporting printf). I can not see any compiler issue and none was brought up. It's a straight CS issue.

Answer (score 3):

`%d` prints a number, `%c` prints the character represented by that number. For example, if `s[i]` evaluates to 65, `%d` prints `65` but `%c` (on ASCII-based systems) prints `A`.

The code listing represents a program that outputs its own code again. But it doesn't output *literally* the same program in this case. In C, a character constant like `'0'` gets translated into a number (48, on ASCII systems). So writing 48 here instead of `'0'` gives the same behavior. Note that the loop only deals with the array of characters (which is not shown completely in the PDF).

Answer (score 0):

In the code presented in the linked talk, the `%d` is used to write the values that populate the `char s[]` array.  The values in the array are integers (8-bit signed to be specific) and for initialization C requires them to be given as strings of numeric characters<sup>1</sup>.  If the values were represented as the actual characters they represent they would need to be single-quoted (e.g. `'/'`, as shown in the figure).  Note that the next line (`printf("%s", s);`) does output the array's values as binary characters (e.g. the decimal number 65 is output as the single character `A`, not the two characters `65`<sup>2</sup>).

<sup>1</sup> Yes, this is slightly simplified; e.g. octal notation, etc. can also be used.

<sup>2</sup> Assuming the compiler is using the ASCII character set.